# BTRFS partition not mount parent transid verified failed and child eb corrupted

Tags: files, system

Using BTRFS in the last 3 months with good experience ... until today ... BTRFS is very good, but when happen a problem it is a big trouble.
Using Lubuntu 20.04 64 bits being an partition for root and another for home both being BTRFS. Not swap partition.
home partition BTRFS configured in fstab how being

`defaults,noautodefrag,compress-force=zlib:9,nospace_cache,noatime,commit=36000,max_inline=0`

Allways when system crash I run the command below

`sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress /dev/sda`

if has any error almost allways is "cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated"
I run the command below to fix

`sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress --clear-space-cache v1 /dev/sda`

and after

`sudo btrfs check --force --repair --progress /dev/sda`
Never had problems doing it.

Today the system had crashed. thus had run the command below in sequence in partition home

```
sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress /dev/sda
sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress --clear-space-cache v1 /dev/sda
sudo btrfs check --force --repair --progress /dev/sda
```

When the system was restarted in user login screen not is possible continue loading the system how if the home partition not was mounted.
Starting in recovery mode and running the command below

`sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress /dev/sda`

was that result

```
parent transid verified failed on 30638080 wanted 73427 found 73667
ignoring transid failure
error child eb corrupted : parent byte nr=305725544 item=1 parent level=2 child level=0
error failed to read block groups input/output error
error cannot open filesystem
```

Not is possible mount the home partition

After I had tried several others commands being in sequence

```
btrfs resuce zero-log sda
restarting adding in fstab
usebackuproot
mount -t btrfs -o usebackuproot /dev/<btrfs-device
and again
sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress /dev/sda
```

and nothing fixed with the same error results.

Not bad block or others problems with the disk.
How recover that partition ?

I've been using computers for years and never seen anything like this happen.
See the link about BTRFS when has problems
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHalOdCZO9Q
Now trying learn about ZFS if is good for compression and easy to fix.
Thanks very much for your reply.

Comment: That was a really bad idea to run `btrfs check --force` on a running system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When the file system has problems I run scrub, when has "cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated"  I run sudo btrfs check --force --readonly --progress --clear-space-cache v1 /dev/sda .... well .. not chances to fix ?

Comment: I am using `btrfs` for many years everywhere and it never crashed. Your mount options, especially `commit=36000` are not good, etc. You are doing wrong things.

Comment: That does exactly command option "--clear-space-cache v1" ? in an large partition has an long time disk activity ... is writing anything all time or only reading verifying ? because happen the error message "cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated" and what the correct command to fix it ?